# Reduce the Integration Latency on API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, latency

I have  an API Gateway attached to the Lambda,

Lambda is throwing the Response  within 300ms  on an Average.

But at API Gateway  Level,
Integration Latency sometimes is taking  more time.

I can say this by Capturing the Integration Latency in CloudWatch Logs of API Gateway.

More  Time i.e more  than  29 seconds at  times  and throwing the Gateway TimeOut Exception.

It is causing the total Latency to be more.

Is there a way we can  reduce the Integration Latency at API Gateway Level.
Or Should We live with 504 Timeout Errors at times.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could consider doing:

- move from REST api gateway to [HTTP api gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api.html) if it's not done already. It has less features, but if you are ok with it then you will gain a substantial speed from it, along with lower costs and maintenance simplicity.
- Use provisioned [provisionned concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html#configuration-concurrency-provisioned) to avoid cold starts (comes with increased costs)

I would advise using HTTP api if you are only using lambdas. It's more recent an frankly I think it's a lot easier to understand and use than REST api

Comment: Thank You for your Answer.
We are already in Production.
We are almost using REST everywhere.